# Windows Phone 8 navigation

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigation

I just started developing wp8 apps coming from android. What is the equivalent UI control for an app drawer (android) to be able to quickly change from page to page? I'm looking for the control used to change from page to page in OneNote

EDIT: I found out that Windows phone 8.1 offers flyouts which can be made to look like an app drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to the android app drawer is probably the windows phone appbar, but the appbar in windows phone is not used for navigation - only settings like actions.

In windows phone, navigation is done primarily through your own interface, with heavy use of the BACK button to go to previous pages. The main class you use in windows phone is the `NavigationService`

I don't believe the OneNote uses standard UI components, so you would probably have to create your own

There are plenty of solid resources online that should help. Start here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)